# Permission on reproduction of data extracted from a figure

Tags: copyright, data

I have been studying a recent paper, and wanted to extract the some data from it, in an effort to reproduce it. I wrote to the authors, and got no response, so I got the raw data by digitalizing a figure in the paper where the data is plotted.

Then I made another plot, where I plot  the raw data together with mine on top of each other, to compare them. If I publish this plot and properly cite their paper, do I need to ask them for permission?

It looks like I don't, because this is not like copying and pasting a figure of theirs, but I am not 100% sure.

Please find enclosed the [webpage](https://publishingsupport.iopscience.iop.org/handy-tips-when-is-permission-needed/) of the publishing company where I plan to publish, which contains information on their policy on the matter. The  chapter relevant to my case seems to be [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbGZo.png).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the relevance of the _copyright_ tag?

Comment: Figure reproduction is related to copyright, see for example this guideline from Wiley https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/%28ISSN%292198-3844/homepage/2749_Copyright_permissions.pdf .

Comment: You aren't reproducing a figure, you're recreating it, which I think is different. (Does Wiley contradict that? Perhaps you can provide a quote?)

Comment: You may be right, I do not know much about this topic, which is why I asked the question in the first place. Please remove the tag if you think that it is inappropriate. Also, I added the specific quote from the publishing company in the original post. May you please confirm me if I still do not need permission? Thank you

Comment: I've updated my answer https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/132133/22768

Answer (score 1):

> I plot the raw data together with mine

The plot is yours, the data is theirs.

> If I publish this plot and properly cite their paper, do I need to ask them for permission?

No, the citation (and suitable explanation) suffices to attribute the data source. Indeed, as noted by the [referenced source](https://publishingsupport.iopscience.iop.org/handy-tips-when-is-permission-needed/) (under the heading *Reuse of graphs/tables...*):

```
...reuse of raw data does not generally need permission, provided you have plotted 
it into a different graph/table. You should however cite the source of the data.
```

Comment: Thank you. Do I really need to include an explanation of how I extracted the data from their figure?

Comment: Some text has to introduce the citation. So, at the very least, something like, "using data from A et al. [X]."

Comment: I see, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the United States, factual information such as data cannot be protected by copyright law.  If the data is published, it is not a trade secret.  So you may copy without permission.  However, I suggest you ask for permission anyway, as a courtesy.  The authors should be pleased to hear that you were interested in their data.

I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice.

Comment: Thank you. Like I said, I have already tried to contact them, but they did not reply.